# How to enumerate IIS virtual directories with vbscript

Tags: iis, vbscript

I have a vbscript I wrote several years ago that lists all the sites on an IIS server with various attributes. I have been trying to modify this to also list the path(s) of each virtual directory, but neither "application" nor "applicationcollection" seem to be a child element of the site element. I have looked through the MS documentation but their example code only shows adding applications, not listing them.

This is what I have so far:

```
Set adminManager = Wscript.createObject("Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager")
adminManager.CommitPath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
Set sitesSection = adminManager.GetAdminSection("system.applicationHost/sites", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST")
Set sitesCollection = sitesSection.Collection
For siteCount = 0 To CInt(sitesCollection.Count)-1
    Set siteElement = sitesCollection(siteCount)

'Various other bits here....

'Then this line doesn't work. I can't figure out how to reference the application
Set appCollection = siteElement.ChildElements.Item("applicationCollection").Collection
Next
```

Could someone post some example vbscript for listing the virtual directories of the site?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/107619/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-websites-from-iis-showing-the-host-header-value-descript - I've tested this up to Windows 2012 - it works.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that script before, but it has a couple of problems - firstly it uses WMI and so requires IIS6 WMI compatibility to be installed, which is not available on the machines I'm working with. Secondly it only lists the primary path of each site, not other virtual directories.
I'd like to use the admin manager, like I have in my script above. I can get all the other attributes. I just can't figure out how to reference the apps or the virtual directories.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured this out, with help from the very useful [IIS Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference). This now displays "[application] physicalpath"

```
Set siteCollection = siteElement.Collection
spath = ""
For appCount = 0 To CInt(siteCollection.Count)-1
  Set appElement = siteCollection.Item(appCount)
  Set appCollection = appElement.Collection
  For vdCount = 0 To CInt(appCollection.Count)-1
    Set vdElement = appCollection.Item(vdCount)
    spath = spath & "[" & CStr(appElement.Properties.Item("path").Value) & "] " & CStr(vdElement.Properties.Item("physicalPath").Value) & VbCrLf
  Next

Next
```